# QGIS Server WFS query with BBOX filter of size 0

Tags: wfs, extents, qgis-server

I'm trying to query QGIS WFS service for a specific feature for a specific point (lat/lng) value.

(The use case - I have a customer's coordinates for his address, and I want to take from the layer of neighbourhoods the name of the area he lives in).

I was succeeded to enter this query:

```
http://10.253.69.120/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&MAP=/home/user/Documents/MyFirst.qgz&TYPENAME=JerusalemGIS_GPL0&PROPERTYNAME=CODE,SCHN_NAME&BBOX=215841.9,630761.9,217380.9,632096.2
```

And get back these results:

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/wfs.xsd http://www.qgis.org/gml http://10.253.69.120/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=/home/user/Documents/MyFirst.qgz&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&TYPENAME=JerusalemGIS_GPL0&OUTPUTFORMAT=text/xml; subtype%3Dgml/3.1.1">
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:2039">
<gml:lowerCorner>215841.9 630761.9</gml:lowerCorner>
<gml:upperCorner>217380.9 632096.2</gml:upperCorner>
</gml:Envelope>
</gml:boundedBy>
<gml:featureMember>
<qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0 gml:id="JerusalemGIS_GPL0.14">
<qgs:CODE>56</qgs:CODE>
<qgs:SCHN_NAME>בית הכרם</qgs:SCHN_NAME>
</qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>
<qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0 gml:id="JerusalemGIS_GPL0.15">
<qgs:CODE>60</qgs:CODE>
<qgs:SCHN_NAME>בית וגן</qgs:SCHN_NAME>
</qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>
<qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0 gml:id="JerusalemGIS_GPL0.41">
<qgs:CODE>240</qgs:CODE>
<qgs:SCHN_NAME>הר הרצל</qgs:SCHN_NAME>
</qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>
<qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0 gml:id="JerusalemGIS_GPL0.42">
<qgs:CODE>248</qgs:CODE>
<qgs:SCHN_NAME>הר נוף</qgs:SCHN_NAME>
</qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>
<qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0 gml:id="JerusalemGIS_GPL0.52">
<qgs:CODE>228</qgs:CODE>
<qgs:SCHN_NAME>יד ושם - הר הז</qgs:SCHN_NAME>
</qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>
<qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0 gml:id="JerusalemGIS_GPL0.75">
<qgs:CODE>488</qgs:CODE>
<qgs:SCHN_NAME>עין כרם</qgs:SCHN_NAME>
</qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>
<qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0 gml:id="JerusalemGIS_GPL0.86">
<qgs:CODE>568</qgs:CODE>
<qgs:SCHN_NAME>קריית היובל</qgs:SCHN_NAME>
</qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0>
</gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Which are correct.

But when I tried to 'be clever' and just put the upper-right value for the BBOX to be equal to the lower-left value (What I assumed was that I'll have a BBOX in a size of one point) - I don't get the neighbourhood name of that point.

How can I work-around this and get a feature for a specific point?

Comment: Use some other filter, like Intersects.

Comment: Thanks for that! @user30184. I googling for about an hour now to find another option and syntax of querying with Intersects filter against Qgis server, without success yet. Would you please show me an example?

Comment: Maybe the MapServer GET examples would work with QGIS server as well http://mapserver.github.io/uk/ogc/filter_encoding.html#use-of-filter-encoding-in-mapserver.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Off topic but I wonder what WFS version QGIS server decides to use if there is none included in the GetFeature request. It should have an effect on coordinate axis order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `Intersects` filter:

```
FILTER=<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><Intersects><PropertyName>the_geom</PropertyName><gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:coordinates>-74.817265,40.5296504</gml:coordinates></gml:Point></Intersects></Filter>
```